# Which users are necessary on Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, users, daemon

I want to know which users are necessary for a Unix/Linux system. I found [a doc](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html) which told me that there were three necessary users: root, bin, and daemon.

For the user bin and the user daemon, I still can't understand what they are used for. Here is how the doc described them:

> Notes: The bin User ID/Group ID is included for compatibility with
> legacy applications. New applications should no longer use the bin
> User ID/Group ID. 
> The daemon User ID/Group ID was used as an
> unprivileged User ID/Group ID for daemons to execute under in order to
> limit their access to the system. Generally daemons should now run
> under individual User ID/Group IDs in order to further partition
> daemons from one another.

Comment: No other user than root is _necessary_. What is your goal?

Comment: @Kusalananda  My goal is to know which users are necessary, meaning that which users can't be removed otherwise the system will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What are the `bin` and `daemon` users used for?

First, note that the document you’re referring to is the Linux Standard Base, and it lists requirements for systems to be considered LSB-compliant, not for them to be viable in general.

A long time ago, dæmons ran as root. This was eventually considered to be undesirable, since it meant that any dæmon could do anything it wanted in the system. So the `daemon` user was introduced: dæmons ran as user `daemon`, so they were limited to what that user could do.

The reasons for `bin` are [in a similar vein, and have been obsolete for thirty years](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485505/86440)...

Nowadays, as mentioned in the LSB, they are only present for legacy reasons, *i.e.* to be able to run ancient software which assumes those users are present. Current software doesn’t need them.

### What users are necessary on a Linux/Unix system?

The short answer to that is, whatever users are used by the system.

However, all Linux and Unix-style systems have policies which specify that a certain baseline can be assumed. This includes default system users and groups; see for example [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#uid-and-gid-classes) (which defines the framework) and [the master list of Debian system users](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/blob/master/passwd.master). Any Debian package can assume that those users are present: Policy specifies that they are

> the same on every Debian system

(although Debian Policy is descriptive, not normative, it does set up a number of assumptions which the rest of Debian relies on).

So you can in theory remove any user and group which your system doesn’t currently use; however that may cause future breakage, as you install new packages or upgrade existing ones. (Admittedly, this is highly unlikely for `bin` and `daemon`.)